# Row_Number with Teradata GROUPBY

Tags: sql, teradata, row-number

I am trying to determine how I can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function with TERADATA using the result set below. Here is what i have tried:

```
select col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by col2  ) 
    FROM
     (select col1, col2 
    from TABLE
    ORDER BY col2) A
```

Result Set

```
38  11/14/2016  1
38  11/15/2016  2
38  11/16/2016  3
38  11/17/2016  4
38  11/18/2016  5
38  11/19/2016  6
39  11/20/2016  7
39  11/21/2016  8
39  11/22/2016  9
39  11/23/2016  10
39  11/24/2016  11
39  11/25/2016  12
```

Expected:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
38  11/14/2016  1
38  11/15/2016  1
38  11/16/2016  1
38  11/17/2016  1
38  11/18/2016  1
38  11/19/2016  1
39  11/20/2016  2
39  11/21/2016  2
39  11/22/2016  2
39  11/23/2016  2
39  11/24/2016  2
39  11/25/2016  2
```

Comment: Which version of teradata are you using?

Comment: 14.10.06.10 D2D

Comment: Then `DENSE_RANK()` should work

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT col1, 
       col2,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER by col2) AS row_index 
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY col2
```

Well, it seems like you actually need:

```
SELECT col1, 
       col2,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER by col1) AS row_index 
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY col2
```

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff

Comment: I want to group by col1 and order by col2 then create from that order the row number. The partition seems to change my result set?

Comment: @Warz how is it changing your result set?

Comment: sorry for the poor wording. I guess I am trying to build a result set that's ordered col 2 first (maintain that order). Then partition that result set by col1 to show the row number so I can see what each row number looks like. I will update question

Comment: @Warz Then you can just add an `ORDER BY` clause (I updated my answer)

Comment: Thanks for the update. How can i group by on this statement by col1?

Comment: @Warz I'm just not clear what you want. The query was supposed to give you the result you wanted according to the sample data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158879/discussion-between-warz-and-lamak).

Comment: The 2nd command is right on the money for me. Thanks!!